Combine N Json Objects Together in an array with AWS Step Functions or JSONPath
I have a JSON object with an array of N headers in it each in their own object like this:
{
"Headers": [
    {
      "HeaderName1": "HeaderValue1"
    },
    {
      "HeaderName2": "HeaderValue2"
    },
    ...
  ]
}

I would like to combine all of the objects in the array (which doesnt have a set length) to be one singular JSON object like this:
{
  "Headers": {
    "HeaderName1": "HeaderValue1",
    "HeaderName2": "HeaderValue2"
    ...
  }
}

Solution has to be executed using JSONPath or built in AWS Step Function logic and I would much prefer if it could be done without a lambda

JSON Path doesn't perform transformations, it just queries.  If AWS is retiring JSON Path, then you'll need to do some manipulation in code before you call them.
